# Prove gN in G/N has infinite order.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a Group and let g in G. Let g have infinite order and suppose that N is a finite normal subgroup of G. Prove that the Element gN in G/N has infinite Order.

I started by proving by contradiction. So suppose there exists a smallest positive integer n such that $(gN)^n=N$  (Recall that N is the identity in $G/N$.) Then we have $g^n N = (gN)^n=N$. Thus, $g^n$ is in N.

Now I am stuck. I want to say that this contradicts the fact that g has infinite order, but I'm not sure if that is correct or how I would get to this conclusion. I also haven't used the fact that N is finite and normal.

Please help.

Comment: If $g^n\in N$ and $N$ is finite what can you say about $g^n$? Also, you used the normality of $N$ to even talk about $gN$ having an order in $G/N$: the coset space $G/N$ is not a group if $N$ isn't normal.

Comment: Every finite group $H$ is such that there exists $m$ with $g^m=e$ for every $g\in H$.

Comment: Then $g^n$ Must be finite as well?

Comment: Not "be finite," but have finite order, yes. Every element of a finite group has finite order. (Which is weaker than @Euler88's comment about the finite groups having finite exponent, which isn't necessary to state.) What does it mean for $g^n$ to have finite order?

Comment: So if $g^n$ has finite order Then there exists a smallest positive integer m such that $(g^n)^m = e$ but that implies that the Order of g is nm which implies the Order of g is finite which is a contradiction

Comment: Technically it only implies the order of $g$ is $\le nm$ (you can go on to prove that $nm$ would have to be the order, but that involves more work than is strictly necessary). But yes.

Comment: Okay but Saying the Order is less than nm implies g has finite order correct?

Answer (score 2):

If $N$ is finite, then every element of $N$ has finite order. Since $g^n \in N$, $g^n$ has finite order, thus:

$(g^n)^k = e$ for some $k > 0$, that is: $g^{kn} = e$, contradicting that $g$ has infinite order.

P.S.: you *already* used the fact that $N$ is normal, when you said $(gN)^n = g^nN$, which only holds if coset multiplication does-that is, if $N$ is normal.

P.P.S.: perhaps it is not self-evident a finite group contains only elements of finite order. One *could* use Lagrange: if $|N| < \infty$, and $g \in N$, then $\langle g\rangle$ is a subgroup of $N$, and its order (which is the order of the *element* $g$, as well) is thus a divisor of $|N|$ and all such divisors are, of course, finite. However, even this is unnecessary-since $N$ is finite, the distinct positive powers of $g$ must be finite, and so for two positive integers $k < m$, we must have $g^k = g^m$ and thus $g^{m-k} = e$, showing the order of $g$ is finite (it might be less than $m-k$, but certainly no larger).